# rails-vim status line shows `(1 of n): create` after generating a resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim

After generating a resource (controller) using

```
:Generate controller entries

[No write since last change]
      create  app/controllers/entries_controller.rb
      invoke  erb
      create    app/views/entries
      invoke  test_unit
      create    test/controllers/entries_controller_test.rb
      invoke  helper
      create    app/helpers/entries_helper.rb
      invoke    test_unit
      invoke  assets
      invoke    coffee
      create      app/assets/javascripts/entries.coffee
      invoke    scss
      create      app/assets/stylesheets/entries.scss
```

vim-rails is showing `(1 of 6): create` in the status line / command window.

Also, the current buffer has automatically loaded the first created resource.

Does this mean rails-vim has loaded all the files generated by rails? If yes, how to traverse through those list of files one by one?

Comment: how do you generate that? with vim-rails? probably with `:copen` or `:lopen`

Comment: Yes, Generate is a vim-rails command. More info here https://github.com/tpope/vim-rails/blob/master/doc/rails.txt

Comment: yeah I am aware of tpopes `vim-rails` plugin. Your question just doesn't make it clear. And if you already know the link to the docu, please go ahead and read what it states next to the command you are inserting in your vim...

Comment: Because of you I read the documentation once again and realized that `quickfix` is a vim feature not vim-rails. Looked into quickfix and found that I can use `:cn` and `:cp` to traverse the loaded files. Thanks

Comment: and as said, you can open it with `:copen`. see my first comment...

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo +1 for your comment about `:copen`. I didn't understand it at first, now I do ^^